# Collegiate walk-on becoming a statistical all-time leader

Tags: american-football, history, collegiate, trivia

In 2012, quarterback Matt McGloin became the all-time leader in career passing touchdowns, with 45, at Penn State University<sub>([1](http://www.collegian.psu.edu/mobile.aspx?u=/blogs/footblog/2012/11/19/matt_mcgloin_earns_big_ten_honors.aspx))</sub>. McGloin started his college career as a walk-on<sub>([2](http://www.collegian.psu.edu/mobile.aspx?u=/blogs/footblog/2012/11/27/matt_mcgloin_named_burlsworth_trophy_finalist.aspx))</sub>.

In collegiate history, noteably at a Division I FBS level, has there been a walk-on QB or player that became the all-time leader in a major statistical category (TDs, yards, sacks, interceptions, etc.) at his university?

<sub>NOTE: [Clay Matthews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_Matthews_III), now a linebacker with the Green Bay Packers, was a walk-on at the University of Southern California.</sub>

Comment: I dont know about leading statistical categorys but I know Jordy Nelson was a walkon at k-state and Aaron Rodgers started at a junior college because of lack of scholarship offers. Michael Strahan, Terrell Owens, and Tony Romo all atleast started out outside the division 1 ranks because of no scholarship offers

Comment: @Maniac ahh, very interesting. Cam Newton even honed his skills at a junior college before playing at Auburn (backed Tim Tebow up in Florida before his jr. college days).

Comment: oh yes that is another one that I forgot about! That is interesting, On the pro side there are people like James Harrison who went undrafted but developed into a great linebacker or Tom Brady as a 6th round draft choice... the list goes on :)

Comment: Cam Newton reportedly went to a Jr. College not to hone his skills but because he was involved in a cheating scandal.  Just sayin.'

Comment: Newton and Rodgers are NOT walk-ons.  Newton got in trouble so went to Juco.  He was the most heavily recruited athlete at Auburn - so the exact opposite of a walk-on.  Rodgers also went to Juco because he didn't like the schools that gave him offers.  A walk-on should be someone that didn't get a D-1 offer not someone who turned down others because he wanted to go to a school that was out of athletic scholarships.  Also players with good grades often get great academic scholarships at big schools allowing schools to use team scholarships on the dumber kids.

Comment: Junior college is also often used for folks who can't meet NCAA academic standards; a bit more common in basketball I think.  Some schools, such as NMSU in the 80s/early 90s, famously ran entire basketball programs off of JuCo juniors who were very good but not academically eligible out of HS.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of football players who have excelled at their respective universities after beginning their careers as walk-ons. Such players include Colt Brennan, who after being thrown out of the University of Colorado joined Hawaii as a walk-on. By the time of his graduation he had thrown for 131 TDs and in excess of 14000 yards.

Another great walk-on was JJ Watt at Wisconsin. Though I am unsure if he owns any school records he certainly has proved himself at the NFL level.

CBS sports has covered this issue for the BCS era http://www.cbssports.com/collegefootball/eye-on-college-football/21669854